# Wordpress Load Menu onto another installation using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Hi im using Wordpress for my website and have created a plugin, in this plugin im using Jquery to load data from a website to my other one. I have managed this ok with the following code. My issue is that im trying to load a wp-nav menu which has role restriction set on certain menu items. When i load the menu on another site it shows all the navigation links except the ones which you need to be logged in to see. So all ok so far.

I created a new wordpress install an wish to load the menu into this site, i am logged in with the same role as the other site and i cannot still see the menu items which my role allows me to see on the first website. How can i load external data which will allow me to see the same menu items?

in basic terms ive created a wordpress menu and i am trying to use Jquery .Load to load it onto a seperate install of wordpress so the menus are identical. This means i only have to update one menu. I can load the menu data but it doesnt have role access etc (understandable) but want to know how to do this.

```
<script>    
(function($) {  
    //Load div from address
    $(function(){
    var contentURI= 'http://192.168.1.99/intranet #menu-department-menu';
    $('#tabs-1 #scroller').load('/php/loadexternalurl.php?url='+ contentURI);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>

<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); ?> //used to load external data
```

Comment: do the two installations use the same database?

Comment: no they dont, i use a plugin to sync the users across domains which are on different servers and database.